# Can a scale invariant shape be drawn?

Tags: geometry

I'd like to know if an absolute scale invariant shape can be drawn on paper. just like the case that a circle is rotation invariant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it all to fit on a finite sheet of paper, it must be a single point.

Comment: can you please describe in a bit more detail that how is it scale invariant ( like there is white area around a black point which as drawn, and upon zooming by some scale factor with zoom center at that point, ultimately i will be seeing all black area which was different from initial representation of point).

Comment: I'm talking about a mathematical point, which will still look like a point no matter how much you zoom in.